# Reading a raw ptr after all owning shared_ptrs are destroyed: is this undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I thought about this problem while removing nodes in a list in c++:

if I have a doubly linked list node that uses shared_ptr to hold references to adjacent nodes

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> prev;
}
```

If I remove a node from the list, but keep a raw ptr reference to it, like so:

```
Node* curr = randomNode.get();

if(curr->prev) {
    curr->prev->next = curr->next;
}
if(curr->next) {
    curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
}

process(curr->data);
```

Is the access of `curr->data` undefined behaviour? There surely is a chance that the memory has been freed because all ownership has been relinquished (adjacent nodes owned `curr`).

upon testing and debugging this function, the raw ptr is still pointing to valid memory with the correct data. It doesn't appear to be undefined behavior unless I am incorrectly destroying the owners.

Comment: The compiler and runtime environment doesn't do any pointer validation checking. It's up to you as the programmer to make sure your program doesn't access memory that is no longer owned by it. So if memory have been free'd or deleted, then you should just not access that memory.

Comment: isn't `randomNode` a shared_ptr that's still alive?

Comment: But are they destroyed? Seeing as both `next` and `prev` are `shared_ptr` I think you're going to have a nasty circular reference problem. One of them should be non-owning, a `weak_ptr` or a raw pointer.

Comment: With that said, what is the life-time of `randomNode`? Will it be beyond the call to `process`? Then your code is fine, because `randomNode` still exists.

Comment: *There surely is a chance that the memory has been freed because all ownership has been relinquished (adjacent nodes owned curr).*  Surely, indeed you are correct.  The chance is 100%.

Comment: I think we need to see more to give concrete, testable answers. Could you put together a [mre]?

Comment: A linked list also shouldn't be using `shared_ptr` in the first place. There is no need for ownership to be shared because you know when exactly you want objects to be destroyed. At best it should be `unique_ptr` with a decision whether ownership is forward or backward in the chain. However, implementing that correctly is also tricky because one needs to be mindful of stack depth. Implementing a deeply-nested data structure like this is one of the rare cases where using raw pointers for ownership may be preferable.

Comment: *"the raw ptr is still pointing to valid memory with the correct data"* -- Is it? Or did you merely "[sneak into your old room with your stolen key, and look in the drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794)"? It can be very difficult to determine if memory is still valid.